# Register/create a named function programatically in PHP

Tags: php, function, custom-function

Is it possible to programatically register/create a named function in PHP, inside the global scope?

This is possible with `create_function` (before PHP 7+) and nowadays it's possible with anonymous/lambda functions, but then again you either let them be invoked or you assign them to a variable or an object property, then just invoke them with `()` at the end.

What I'm interested if it's anyhow possible to add a new named function in a scope which does not have to be assigned to a variable and accessed with `$functionName`?

Some solution what I'm looking for is:

```
create_named_function('fullname', function($firstname, $lastname) {
    return $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
});
```

Then I'd have it accessible like `fullname(params...)`.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this ?

Comment: interesting question, but hacky for real life usages

Comment: I can't think of a way without eval()

Comment: As I know, the only way is writting PHP extension.

Comment: How about? https://3v4l.org/s2N50 ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You have to post code from link as answer here)

Comment: Nice question, but could you please explain why do you need this?)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I'm trying to achive more abstraction and flow control with defining functions, and trying to avoid having them named / referenced to variables. I'm taking a look at possible solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it should be encouraged to do this - it stops all sort of useful things being able to check code and code completion in IDE's.

BUT...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$body = <<< 'FN'
<?php
function fullname($firstname, $lastname) {
    return $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
}
FN;

file_put_contents("func.php", $body);
require "func.php";

echo fullname("Joe", "Bloggs");
```

The first part creates an include file with the required code (note the use of Nowdoc string, which allows the inclusion of variables without them being substituted).  This could be any form of code generation.

Answer (score 2):

Here example with `eval`:

```
<?php

$functionName = 'foo';
$f = '
  function ' . $functionName . '($a) {
    var_dump($a);
  }
';
// Finger crossed!)))
eval($f);
// Now you have function "foo" in your global scope!)
$functionName('bar');
// It will print
// string(3) "bar"
```

But you have to have clear vision what are you really doing here... because it's really tricky place...